# Авторизация через твиттер

Tags: android, twitter-api

В приложении имеется блок авторизации через твиттер. 
Ниже приведен кусок кода в котором задается ключ и секретный ключ.

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
```

Имеется два аккаунта твиттера, один был заблокировани к нему доступа нет, первоначально именно в нем и было привязано android приложение, и с его key,secret появляется экран авторизации. Но поскольку аккаунт заблокирвоан, было решено завести новый аккаунт, в котором я создал приложение, затем полученные ключ и секрет прописал в android приложении, но теперь при попытке открытия экрана авторизации твиттера появляется ошибка

```
    05-31 12:20:27.000 28534-28534/ru.xxxxxx.yyyyy E/Twitter: Invalid json: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <hash>
              <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
              <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
            </hash>

            com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeListAdapter$1.read(SafeListAdapter.java:45)
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeMapAdapter$1.read(SafeMapAdapter.java:45)
                at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
                at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
                at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
                at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.parseApiError(TwitterApiException.java:111)
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.readApiError(TwitterApiException.java:96)
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.<init>(TwitterApiException.java:44)
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
                at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
                at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeListAdapter$1.read(SafeListAdapter.java:45) 
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeMapAdapter$1.read(SafeMapAdapter.java:45) 
                at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887) 
                at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852) 
                at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801) 
                at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773) 
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.parseApiError(TwitterApiException.java:111) 
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.readApiError(TwitterApiException.java:96) 
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.<init>(TwitterApiException.java:44) 
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42) 
                at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68) 
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
            05-31 12:20:27.001 28534-28534/ru.xxxxxx.yyyyy E/Twitter: Failed to get request token
            com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 401
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
                at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
05-31 12:20:27.013 28534-28534/ru.xxxxxx.yyyyy E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error
            com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:95)
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:194)
                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
                at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Итак, в новом аккаунте твиттер надо было указать имя приложения, но т.к в заблокированном аккаунте уже использовалось оригинальное имя приложения, то пришлось указать оригинальное имя + в конце добавить символ.

Подскажите как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: У вас четко написан тип выпадающего исключения - JsonSyntaxException копайте что не так у вас с Json. Может в нем где-то захардкожены старые учетные данные?

Comment: а может ли данная ошибка появляться из за несоответствия реального названия приложения и указанного в twitter dev ?

Comment: вполне вероятно - может из твиттера идет json с именем старым, и при парсинге вылетает ошибка.